# Magento 2 product image on product page load slowly

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, image

I'm using Magento 2.2.3 with a theme based on luma theme, no change did to the product images gallery. Images have all low size, even so, it takes like 3-4 seconds to load the first image. I have tried the Xumulus extension, but is not really a great choice, as it loads the image first, but delay all the js, so for a few seconds can't do pretty much nothing, like adding to cart.

Comment: Is cache enable or disabled?

Comment: yes, I'm using varnish cache

Answer (score 0):

Run this **cli** command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy